# Regex to match an URL without a trailing slash also no file extension

Tags: regex

I'm utterly confused by reading so many regular expression articles so far on this.

I am looking to match the first URL, the rest should not match:

```
https://subdomain.example.com/test <== only this should match
https://subdomain.example.com/paht/test.css
https://subdomain.example.com/path/path/test.js
https://example.com/test/
```

I am looking to match only the routes that have no trailing slashes or file extensions.

Here is my regex: `https:.*^(?!([^\/]|(\.[a-z]{2,8})))$`

You can try here: https://regexr.com/5dic8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
^https?:\/\/(?:.*\/)?[^\/.]+$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/NpQaYq/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\/.]+                  any character except: '\/', '.' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: All SO answers should be like this. Thank you.

Comment: @LearnerFor-life totally agree, it is so nice see answers like this!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you're only matching urls you also can reverse the url and use:

```
^\w+\/
```

- `^` Only at the beginning (which in this case is the end)
- `\w+` Any set of alphanumeric chars where there is at least one
- `\/` To match the slash

Would be something like this in python:

```py
re.search(r'^\w+\/', url[::-1])
```

If this is not `None` then `url` ends like: `.../someword`.

**NOTE:** this is only if you are sure that `url` is a url indeed.