# Add missing slashes to all the urls in the wordpress database using Search Regex Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, search-regex

I am using [Search Regex](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/) plugin to update some content in the Wordpress database and have managed to replace string (i.e. replace all instance of `stringone` with `stringtwo`)  but I am looking into finding all the urls in are in the database that don't have a trailing slash and add one at the end. This task seems to be bit challanging with this plugin.

The url `https://www.test.com/path/otherpath` becomes `https://www.test.com/path/otherpath/`

There must be other ways to accomplish this task so would be good to have some idea. PS - I am new to wordpress and php. Thanks

I have tried finding similar issues on stack overflow and
reading `Search Regex` documentation to do this without much success.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is usually the way to go, you need to transform your search to a regex expression to get all appearences without trailing slash

For your example, that would be:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:.*\/)?[^\/.]+$
```

See also: [Regex to match an URL without a trailing slash also no file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252012/regex-to-match-an-url-without-a-trailing-slash-also-no-file-extension)

The replacement would be the original value  + "/". I don't know the plugin but it should be possible to set this.